# Delete distinct multiple columns in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

I have Query in Access that I'm building in SQL Server.
Access:

```
DELETE DISTINCT * from [TableA] INNER JOIN TableB
ON [TableA].[Column1]=[TableB].[column1]
AND [TableA].[Column2]=[TableB].[column2]
```

I know I could use

```
Delete from tableA where ID in (
Select * from from [TableA] INNER JOIN TableB
ON [TableA].[Column1]=[TableB].[column1]
AND [TableA].[Column2]=[TableB].[column2])
```

But I get an error saying "Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS"

My Goal is to delete the Distinct records from the Access query mentioned at the top.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to delete the rows in `TableA` that are in `TableB`, according to the column matches.  How about doing this:

```
delete from tableA
    where exists (select 1
                  from tableB
                  where tableA.Column1 = tableB.Column1 and tableA.column2 = tableB.column2
                 );
```

This seems to be the intent of what you are trying to do.

Comment: This works perfect but Select 1 gives every row in the select query. Where as I need to delete only the Distinct columns as done by the Access query. Could you throw some light on that.

Comment: @Lewan how do you think `distinct` affects this? Do you only want to delete rows that occur once in `TableB` or do you only want to delete rows that occur multiple times in `TableB`? Both are things that can be achieved, but not using the `distinct`-keyword.

Answer (score 1):

In the sub-query u have to select the ID column from the respective table that is the only column u need

```
DELETE a
FROM   tableA a
       JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT Column1 ,column2 
             FROM   tableA
             WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1
                            FROM   tableB
                            WHERE  tableA.Column1 = tableB.Column1
                                   AND tableA.column2 = tableB.column2)) b
         ON A.Column1 = B.Column1
            AND A.column2 = B.column2
```

Comment: Pradeep I need to Delete only (DELETE DISTINCT * from [TableA]). Any idea how to edit the query you provided accordingly. I dont have an ID Column in the tables

Comment: I will let you know once I do validation of records using both queries